# Which collection is suitable for tel number + name pair in Java?

Tags: java, loops, collections, multimap

I am trying to add to a collection the following pairs

> 698xxxxxxx   -   personA
>
> 698xxxxxxx   -   personB
>
> 699xxxxxxx   -   personA
>
> 699xxxxxxx   -   personB

I go through alot of files and try to add to a collection the pairs i find there. I want to be able to have a table that will show each number and what people it was correlated with without having dublicate PAIRS. for example

> 1-personA ok
>
> 1-personB ok
>
> 2-personA ok
>
> 3-personB ok
>
> 3-personB NOT OK as its already there

I tried using a Multimap but i m not sure if its the right choice. Whatever the solution is please show me how to iterrate through its values as well so i can use the pairs. Sorry for the demanding post but i m new with Java and i find a lil hard to understand the APIs.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Consuder uing a HashMap. but think what is your unique key, tel + person, or tel.

Answer (score 3):

There are three obvious alternative, depending on what you require.

- If there can only be one person for each phone number, then a simple `Map<PhoneNo, Name>`.
- If there a given phone number can be associated with multiple people, then either a `Map<Phone,Set<Name>>` or a multi-map class.
- If you also want to find out the phone number or numbers for each person, you need two maps or two multi-maps ... or a bidirectional map.

There is a secondary choice you need to make: hash-table versus tree-based organizations.  A hash table will give you `O(1)` lookup/insert/remove (assuming that the hash function is good).  A tree-based implementation gives `O(logN)` operations ... but it also allows you to iterate over the entries (or values) in key order.

While the standard Java class libraries don't provide multi-maps or bidirectional maps, they can easily be implemented by combining the simple collection classes.

Answer (score 1):

You can choose Map Interface in Java, which accepts key and value pairs.

You can have this as a reference: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_map_interface.htm

Answer (score 0):

You may need a hashmap with the key as the name of the person and value as a HashSet of numbers. Hashset does not allow duplicates, so duplicate numbers will not be stored in that. Here is the code:

```
HashMap<String,HashSet> Records;
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java there is a couple of options. If you don't know about the cardinality of persons or numbers, then go for:

```
public class Pair {
  String person;
  String number;
  }
```

Then use a Set to be save from doublettes like

```
Set<Pair> pairs = new HashSet<>();
....
pairs.add( new Pair( "689xxxx", "personA" );
for ( Pair pair : pairs ) {
  System.out.println( pair.number + " - " + pair.person );
}
```

Hajo